# How to convert current date to float which is stored in excel as date?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I can convert date read from excel to a proper date using xldate_as_tuple function. Is there any function which can do the reverse i.e. convert proper date to float which is stored as date in excel ?

Comment: I can't speak for a existing function but you can write your own.  The Excel date serial number is the number of days since Jan 1, 1900.  Just do a date diff in days and you have the answer.

Comment: Heh, Excel doesn't know about Epoch? :)

Comment: @PortlandRunner it's actually from Dec 31, 1899. For an explanation see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html

Comment: What do you need the Excel date for anyway?  If it's for writing back into an Excel file, both xlwt and XlsxWriter will handle the conversion within their respective `write` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the xlrd [xldate.py](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/xldate.py) module there are several functions, `xldate_from_date_tuple()`, `xldate_from_time_tuple()` and `xldate_from_datetime_tuple()`, which convert datetime objects to Excel series dates.

Also, in the [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) utility.py module there is a function called [`datetime_to_excel_datetime()`](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/xlsxwriter/utility.py#L555) which converts datetime objects for an Excel serial date.

All of these solutions take into account the epoch and the Excel 1900 leapyear bug.

Answer (score 0):

Excel dates are represented as pywintypes.Time type objects. So in order to e.g. assign the current timestamp to a cell you do:

workbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value = pywintypes.Time(datetime.datetime.now())

Answer (score 0):

Almost Bjoern Stiel's answer (tried to up arrow but don't have enough reputation).

Had to add tz_info (used pytz for this):

```
    from win32com.client import Dispatch
    xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Path\to\file")
    d = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.now())
    book.Sheets(1).Cells(2,12).Value = d
```